# Apache shows the contents of MP4 file rather than a download prompt

Tags: apache, mp4

I am running Apache on Linux, and when I go to a url that is a .mp4 file rather than let me download the file it shows the contents of the file (as mangled text)

eg the out put is

��� ftypisom���isomiso2avc1mp41��*moov���lmvhd����̴�d̴�d��������������������������������������������������@��������������������������������Htrak���\tkhd���̴�d̴�d��������������������������������������������������������@������������$edts���elst��������������������mdia��� mdhd����̴�d̴�d����
��������-hdlr��������vide������������VideoHandler���kminf���vmhd��������������

How do I make Apache serve it correctly?

Comment: You should set content type of response

Answer (score 2):

Add a `AddType` directive:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

This will cause Apache to send the correct headers to your browser, which will then select the correct method to download or play the media file.

Make sure you have `mod_mime` installed and activated (but I reckon it is by default; I never had any issues with this).

More information here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html