# how to play video from server?

Tags: android, http, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-ec2

i want to have a URL like this one (https://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4) where when you click it and itll play the video. Thing is this isnt my website or video. i tried my URL which i thought was corrct (http://54.XXX.XXX.238/srv/ProductVideos/lazar108@hotmail.com/s/s_7s.MP4) and it gives me this error:

> The requested URL /srv/ProductVideos/lazar108@hotmail.com/s/s_7s.MP4 was not found on this server.

I know for a fact that theres a video in the file path on my server. Proof:
[image]

(I need this URL for my android app so i can display the video in the app.)

**How can i create a link like this one (https://www.ooklnet.com/files/381/381489/video.mp4)?**

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.4 server with AWS EC2!

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Where are the files in relation to your web root folder?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/766574/whats-my-ec2-video-url

Comment: i can access PHP files in my **/var/www/html** and the files in my question arnt in these folders & yes i tried this community @MattHouser

Comment: Your web server (most likely) will only serve up files under `/var/www/html`. Make sure your files are under that.

Comment: okay ill try this tomorrow and update you! thanks

Comment: @MattHouser i just moved it over and it didnt come up on the browser or app. I tried m EC2 .com and the IP address and they both didnt work

Comment: Where is the file in your OS (full path) and what was the URL you tried?

Comment: i tried using a S3 bucket and that worked so now i am just going to upload my videos to the S3 instead of the EC2 server. Thanks for the help tho!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) your EC2 has to have security groups open to allow any access to port 80 from the Internet

2) your EC2 has to be running some web server software such as apache

3) apache needs to be configured to serve files, check the document root

4) apache needs to be configured to correctly send mp4 with the right mime type headers see this answer [Apache not serving .mp4 files correctly - shows the contents of the file rather than a download prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341453/apache-not-serving-mp4-files-correctly-shows-the-contents-of-the-file-rather)

If it is apache ( and not nginx or another web server) you are using check the access log file `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and the default error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: i decided to upload my videos to a S3 bucket on Amazon and just upload the videos there! thanks for the help tho!!