# How can I display videos from my own computer on my website

Tags: html, css

so I have this website so far

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNRKf.jpg

Looks like that. I want the play thumbnails to display video I have on my computer. I want to use my computer as a video host. I am trying to play around making a video sharing site. I plan on going down the google cloud route to host my videos but as of right now I wanted to know if its possible to use my own computer as a server to retrieve videos I have saved.

Comment: Would you mind letting us know what operating system you use on your personal computer?

Comment: I have windows 10 running but i can always run a VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option...

## Step 1: Serving the video

### Super Simple Node.js Server

(install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/))

At a command-prompt:

1. Run `npm install --global http-server`.
2. Change into (`cd`) the directory where your videos are stored.
3. Run `http-server`.

### Apache + GNU/Linux

1. Run a Linux VM on your computer (or use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) if you're on Windows, or if you must install it directly follow these instructions: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-apache-on-windows/).
2. Install Apache (`sudo apt-get install apache2` on Ubuntu; see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).
3. Put your video in a directory such as `/var/www/html` or the equivalent for your platform (revisit the first two links for help).
4. Configure your new server to serve video correctly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13341700).

## Step 2: On the frontend...

1. Embed a  element on your webpage pointing to the video on the server (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

You're all set up!

TL;DR: you need to serve the videos and then display them. If you want to add logic beyond that, consider building an [Express](https://expressjs.com) web app.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much, this sounds like a great idea. If I then add a button to upload videos from the site where any can upload , I can modify this a bit to have it display recently uploaded videos as well?

Comment: @fdasfhakjh that could be logic on the frontend, but if you want to allow users to upload content you'll need more than simply file serving on the backend (account registration, a database, spam filters). Then you could build a server-side rendered website with Express (https://expressjs.com) that has that recency ordering baked in when the browser requests the page.

Comment: awesome thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your video files in a folder on a server, and then you need to reference them in your code. It's very simple to reference the videos when they are in a folder on a server.

see:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: can I do this using my own computer and just leave it on?

Comment: @fdasfhakjh Yes, you can achieve that using node.js. If you are trying to run a temporary web server while your computer is idle.

Comment: so I have no experience or even know what node.js. could you link me to a guide so I can learn how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: starting a node.js web server: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-start-a-node-server-examples-with-the-most-popular-frameworks/